# Why I have "Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes" on Linux (Gentoo) but not windows7

Tags: mysql, linux, utf-8, indexing

I'm using MySQL5.1.61 with utf8 as encoding. I have two varchar(255) columns. I met the error "Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes" when I tried to create index on the two columns. I searched many stacks which said that utf8 needs 3 bytes for one character. My question is that it works well on Windows7 but not on linux. Is there some special configuration I need to check? Thanks in advance.

============================Edit: I got the answer =================================

It seams a new option of innodb_large_prefix which was introduced since 5.5.14. By default, an index key for a single-column index can be up to 767 bytes. The same length limit applies to any index key prefix. When the innodb_large_prefix configuration option is enabled, this length limit is raised to 3072 bytes, for InnoDB tables that use the DYNAMIC and COMPRESSED row formats.   When you attempt to specify an index prefix length longer than allowed, the length is silently reduced to the maximum length.

It works after upgrade to 5.5.22

Comment: It's a core mysql limitation, not OS dependent. Your Windows setup/table structure must differ from the Linux one.

Comment: It seams a bug of MySQL: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4541

Comment: I got this from the page: If you need this you should really look at MySQL 5.5 and the innodb_large_prefix option that is available from 5.5.14 (July 2011) onwards because it probably does what you are looking for:

"Enable this option to allow index key prefixes longer than 767 bytes (up to 3072 bytes), for InnoDB tables that use the DYNAMIC  and COMPRESSED  row formats.

Comment: @MarcB, you are right. It has nothing to do with OS. Actually, the MySQL version of my Win7 is 5.5. Thank you.